# Understanding the wreath product of $\mathbb Z_2$ by $\mathbb Z_2$ and of $\mathbb Z_2$ by $\mathbb Z_3$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory, dihedral-groups, wreath-product

1) What is a conceptual way to see that the regular wreath product of $\mathbb Z_2 \wr \mathbb Z_2$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_4$ of order $8$?

How should I go about to answer this question? Should I first ask myself how to see that $D_4$ is a semidirect product? Or should I try to write down a presentation of $\mathbb Z_2 \wr \mathbb Z_2$?

1a) How do we see that the $2$-Sylow subgroup of the symmetric group $S_4$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2 \wr \mathbb Z_2$?

2) Now a general theorem says that one can find all extensions of a group $K$ by a group $H$ inside $K \wr H$. How do I in practice find subgroups of $D_4$ which are isomorphic to all extensions of $\mathbb Z_2$ by $\mathbb Z_2$? I mean in this example it is easy since there are two nonequivalent extensions, $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_4$ and I look at the subgroup lattice of $D_4$ to find corresponding subgroups. But how would I go about this in general, e.g. in the next example.

3) Consider another example: $\mathbb Z_2 \wr \mathbb Z_3$. My understanding of this group is this: the base is $H = \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ with $G = \mathbb Z_3$ acting on the base by shifting the entries of a triple. Then the wreath product is the semidirect product $H \rtimes G$ wrt this shifting action. It is a group of order $2^3 \cdot 3 = 24$ elements.  But this is about it how I understand this group. Are there easy observations to be made immediately about this group (just by definition)?

Comment: Perhaps the reason you have had no response is that you have asked a large number of slightly vague questions. There are lots of ways that you could prove that $C_2 \wr C_2$ and a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $S_4$ are both isomorphic to the dihedral group of order $8$. For example, they are both nonabelian groups of order $8$ with more than one element of order $2$, and $D_4$ is the only group with that property. Or you could use presentations and show that all thre groups have the same presentation, such as $\langle x,y,z \mid x^2=y^2=z^2=1, xy=yx,zxz=y \rangle$.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}\DeclareMathOperator{\Sym}{Sym}$This is an answer to question (1)

> What is a conceptual way to see that the regular wreath product of $\mathbb Z_2 \wr \mathbb Z_2$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_4$ of order $8$?

Let $\Omega = \Omega_{1} \cup \Omega_{2}$ be a set which is the disjoint union of two sets $\Omega_{i}$ with $2$ elements each. Then $Z_{2} \wr Z_{2}$ is the group of all the permutations of $\Omega$ which respect the partition $\Set{\Omega_{1}, \Omega_{2}}$, that is, the set of all those $g \in \Sym(\Omega)$ that send  $\Omega_{1}$ to either $\Omega_{1}$ or $\Omega_{2}$, and the same for $\Omega_{2}$.

Now $D_{4}$ is the group of congruences of a square. If the vertices of the square are labelled $1, 2, 3, 4$ consecutively (clockwise, say), then $D_{4}$ preserves the partition of the set $\Omega = \Set{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }$ of the vertices given by the two diagonals $\Omega_{1} = \Set{1, 3}$ and $\Omega_{2} = \Set{2, 4}$.

Now both groups have order $8$, so they must coincide.

Answer (score 0):

At least for the $\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong D_8$ case I can give you this proof:

We want to show that both groups have the same presentation and by that are isomorphic. For the $D_8$ we know the presentation from e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3206327/group-presentations-and-the-dihedral-group).
So
$$
D_8 = \langle a, c \mid a^2, c^2, (ac)^2 \rangle
$$
Also we will be using the fact, that a presentation of a direct product is given as
$$
G \times H = \langle X \mid R \rangle \times \langle Y \mid S \rangle = \langle X \cup Y \mid R \cup S \cup T \rangle
$$
with
$T := \{ xyx^{-1}y^{-1} \} $

For the wreath product we also need a presentation of a semidirect product which can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160870/group-presentation-for-semidirect-products) (The proof can be found in the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1642414/where-can-i-find-a-proof-of-the-presentation-for-semidirect-products))

Now we consider the wreath product as the semidirect product of $S_2 \times S_2$ with $S_2$ as described i.e. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product#Notation_and_conventions)

So we get:
$$
\begin{align}
S_2 \wr S_2 &= (S_2 \times S_2) \rtimes S_2 \\ 
&= (\langle a, b \mid a^2, b^2, (ab)^2 \rangle ) \rtimes S_2
\end{align}
$$

As we have $\phi:S_2 \to Aut(S_2 \times S_2), c^i \mapsto \left( (x, y) \mapsto \begin{cases}
(x, y) &,i=1\\ 
(y, x) &,i=0,2
\end{cases} \right) $
where we consider the $S_2$ as cyclic.

Now we get by the semidirect product presentation definition
$$
(S_2 \times S_2) \wr S_2 = \langle a,b,c \mid a^2, b^2, (ab)^2, c^2, cac=b, cbc=a \rangle
$$
Now we eliminate the $b$ with $b=cac$:
$$
\begin{align}
(S_2 \times S_2) \wr S_2 &= \langle a, b,c \mid a^2, caccac, acacacac, c^2 caccac, ccacca, acac, ccacccac \rangle\\
&= \langle a,c \mid a^2, acacacac, c^2\rangle \\
&= \langle a,c \mid a^2, c^2, (ac)^4\rangle
\end{align}
$$

Now we introduce another parameter $d$ and relation $d=ac$ and get
$$
\begin{align}
&\langle a,c,d \mid a^2, c^2, (ac)^4, d=ac\rangle \\
=&\langle a,c,d \mid a^2, (ad)^2, d^4, d=ac\rangle \\
=&\langle a,d \mid a^2, (ad)^2, d^4\rangle \cong D_8
\end{align}
$$

This can probably also be done for $\mathbb{Z_2} \wr \mathbb{Z}_3$ but I have not tried. If anybody wants to, I recommend GAP for checking your work, as it can do Tietze Transformations with comments.