# Isomorphism between free abelian groups that fit into a short exact sequence

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, exact-sequence, group-extensions, free-abelian-group

Let $A$ and $B$ be free abelian groups and

$0\to A\to B\to\Bbb{Z}/p\to 0$

a short exact sequence.

> Are $A$ and $B$ necessarily isomorphic?

The only examples I can come up with are of the form

$0\to \Bbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\cdot p}\Bbb{Z}\to\Bbb{Z}/p\to 0$

or very similar examples with groups of higher rank. I'm not asking whether the map $A\to B$ is an isomorphism, but if there exists some isomorphism $A\cong B$. I've heard that counterexamples can be built using large cardinals, but I don't know anything about cardinal theory. Any alternative or a detailed explanation with references about cardinals would be appreciated.

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3174538/104041)

Comment: $A$ and $B$ must have the same rank, so yes.

Comment: @DerekHolt why and what about groups of infinite rank?

Comment: There is a standard result that, for any subgroup $A$ of a finitely generated abelian group $B$, there is a free basis $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ of $B$ and positive  integers $d_1,\ldots,d_r$ for some $r < n$ such that $A$ is generated by $d_1b_1,\ldots,d_rb_r$. It follows from that. For infinite rank just observe that $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: @DerekHolt from that it follows that $rank A\leq rank B$, but where do you get equality from? In the infinite case, the same but with cardinalities

Comment: Think about it! What would the quotient be otherwise?

Comment: @DerekHolt ok I see it in the finitely generated case. But I'm not sure why groups of different cardinality cannot yield $\Bbb{Z}/p$ as a quotient. I intuitively see that the difference is too huge but I'd like to see a rigorous argument, since I don't know if there is an analogue of taking coordinates with respect to a free basis.

Comment: Well $B$ is a union of $p$ sets having the same cardinality as $A$, so $B$ must have the same cardinality.