# A short sequence of groups

Tags: group-theory, homological-algebra, normal-subgroups, exact-sequence

Suppose we have a short sequence of groups

\begin{equation*} 0\xrightarrow{} A\xrightarrow{} E\xrightarrow{\pi} G\xrightarrow{} 1.
\end{equation*}

In some books, the authors mention that we can identify $A$ with a normal subgroup of $A$. Why?

I can only show that $A$ is isomorphic to the image of $A$, which can be viewed as a subgroup of $E$.

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3174538/104041)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those authors are assuming that this is a short **exact** sequence of groups.  Exactness means that the image of each map is exactly equal to the kernel of the next map.  In particular, this means that the image of $A \to E$ is equal to the kernel of $E \to G$ and kernels are normal subgroups, hence the image of $A \to E$ is a normal subgroup.