# Correct Way of Writing Extension of Group

Tags: group-theory, terminology, group-extensions

Let $G=C_2\times C_m=\{(g^{t_1},h^{t_2})\mid t_1\in \{0,1\}, t_2\in \{0,1,...,m-1\}\}$.

Is it correct to just say that $G$ is an extension of $C_m$ by $C_2$?

Or it is more accurate to say that $G$ is an extension of $H$ by $C_2$ where $H=\{(1,h^{t_2})\mid t_2\in \{0,1,...,m-1\}\}$.

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3174538/104041)

Comment: These are both correct and accurate. See [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension).

Comment: The first one is not formally correct - you should replace "is" by "is isomorphic  to", but this is a very frequently employed abuse of notation.

Comment: @DerekHolt no, that's formally correct. Being an extension means there's a short exact sequence $1\to C_m\to G\to C_2\to 1$. No "is isomorphic to" is needed.