# Find all the varieties of abelian groups (in the sense of universal algebra)

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

This is **Exercise 2.3.6** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=Find%20all%20the%20abelian%20varieties%20&p=10), it is new to MSE.

*(Note: Here "abelian variety" is not, at least a priori, in the sense given [in this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_variety#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20particularly%20in%20algebraic,be%20defined%20by%20regular%20functions.). See below for details.)*

### The Details:

*These are essentially the same as in [the previous exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4114820/104041) of Robinson's book.*

Since definitions vary, on page 15, *ibid.*, paraphrased, it states that

> A subgroup $N$ of $G$ is *normal* in $G$ if one of the following equivalent statements is satisfied:
>
> (i) $xN=Nx$ for all $x\in G$.
>
> (ii) $x^{-1}Nx=N$ for all $x\in G$.
>
> (iii) $x^{-1}nx\in N$ for all $x\in G, n\in N$.

On page 56, *ibid.*,

> Let $F$ be a free group on a countably infinite set $\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ and let $W$ be a nonempty subset of $F$. If $w=x_{i_1}^{l_1}\dots x_{i_r}^{l_r}\in W$ and $g_1,\dots, g_r$ are elements of a group $G$, we define the *value* of the word $w$ at $(g_1,\dots,g_r)$ to be $w(g_1,\dots,g_r)=g_1^{l_1}\dots g_{r}^{l_r}$. The subgroup of $G$ generated by all values in $G$ of words in $W$ is called the *verbal subgroup* of $G$ determined by $W$,
>
> $$W(G)=\langle w(g_1,g_2,\dots) \mid g_i\in G, w\in W\rangle.$$

On page 57, *ibid.*,

> If $W$ is a set of words in $x_1, x_2, \dots$ and $G$ is any group, a normal subgroup $N$ is said to be *$W$-marginal* in $G$ if
>
> $$w(g_1,\dots, g_{i-1}, g_ia, g_{i+1},\dots, g_r)=w(g_1,\dots, g_{i-1}, g_i, g_{i+1},\dots, g_r)$$
>
> for all $g_i\in G, a\in N$ and all $w(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_r)$ in $W$. This is equivalent to the requirement: $g_i\equiv h_i \mod N, (1\le i\le r)$, always implies that $w(g_1,\dots, g_r)=w(h_1,\dots, h_r)$.
>
> [The] $W$-marginal subgroups of $G$ generate a normal subgroup which is also $W$-marginal. This is called *the $W$-marginal of $G$* and is written $$W^*(G).$$

On page 58, *ibid.*,

> If $W$ is a set of words in $x_1, x_2, \dots $, the class of all groups $G$ such that $W(G)=1$, or equivalently $W^*(G)=G$, is called the *variety* $\mathfrak{B}(W)$ determined by $W$.

### The Question:

> A variety is said to be *abelian* if all its members are abelian. Find all the abelian varieties.

### Thoughts:

It occurred to me to consider two extremes first: where the variety $\mathfrak{W}$ is just the class containing only (the isomorphic copies of) the trivial group and where the variety $\mathfrak{W}$ is the class of all abelian groups. I guess I could get at least one of these extremes by considering

$$\mathfrak{W}=\mathfrak{B}(\{\varepsilon\}),\tag{1}$$

where $\varepsilon$ is the empty word; but something tells me that $(1)$ includes any & all groups, not just abelian ones; I don't know - I'm not particularly confident in calculating it.

Another thought I have is whether an abelian variety might correspond to

$$\mathfrak{W}=\mathfrak{B}(\{ [x_1, x_2]\}),\tag{2}$$

where $[x_1,x_2]=x_1^{-1}x_2^{-1}x_1x_2$ is the commutator of the abstract symbols $x_1,x_2$. Again, I don't know.

Please help :)

Comment: Hint: as we’ve [said before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3907706/verbal-subgroups-of-mathbbz2) every word is equivalent to a commutator word and a power word. In the presence of the word $[x_1,x_2]$, abelian varieties are determined by sets of power words. But if your group satisfies both $x^a$ and $x^b$, then it satisfies $x^{\gcd(a,b)}$. So every abelian variety is completely determined by a pair of words, one of which is $[x_1,x_2]$ and the other is of the form $x^n$ for some $n\geq 0$.

Comment: (It is definitely not in the sense of the Wikipedia article, which is a concept from algebraic geometry; it is in the sense of universal algebra, which corresponds to [this article instead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)).

Comment: Note: the empty word defines the variety of **all** groups. If you want the trivial variety, it is determined by the word $x$: remember that the groups in the variety determined by $w$ are the groups in which every evaluation of $w$ is trivial. With the empty word, you always get the trivial value for every group; so $\mathfrak{W}(e) = \mathscr{G}roup$.

Comment: I can develop all of the above, but I thought you might want to develop this yourself and write up an answer; I’ll be happy to check it if you do. If you’d rather I write up the answer, I can do that too.

Comment: Thank you, @ArturoMagidin

Comment: I'll wait for a day or so then, if I can't flesh out the details, I'll ask you for more help, @ArturoMagidin.

Comment: Okay, I'm stuck. I think (nontrivial) abelian varieties are determined by two words: $[x_1,x_2]$ for distinct $x_1,x_2$, and $x^p$ for some symbol $x$ and some prime $p$, which is to say that $W$ as above is $W=\{[x_1,x_2], x^p\}$. But I'm not sure whether this is true, let alone how to prove it. I don't think it captures the variety of all abelian groups (if such a variety exists). So here I am, asking for help again, please, @ArturoMagidin; I hope you don't mind.

Comment: No problem; I’ll get to it later today. You’re very close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A group is abelian if and only if satisfies the identity $[x_1,x_2]$; that is, if the verbal subgroup determined by $[x_1,x_2]$ (the commutator subgroup) is trivial. So if a set of words $W$ determines a variety all of whose elements are abelian groups, then the set $W'=W\cup\{[x_1,x_2]\}$ determines the same variety: all groups $G$ for which $W(G)=1$ also satisfy $W'(G)=1$, and conversely. Thus, every variety of abelian groups is determined by a set of words $W$ such that $[x_1,x_2]\in W$.

However, the verbal subgroup determined by any word $w$ is equivalent to the verbal subgroup determined by a pair of words, one of which is a commutator word (an element of $[F_{\omega},F_{\omega}]$, where $F_{\omega}$ is the free group on countably many variables), and the other is a power word (a word of the form $x^a$ for some $a\geq 0$). A sketch of this fact can be found [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3907737/742). Thus, we can replace every element of $W$ with a commutator word and a power word. Note that this process does not replace $[x_1,x_2]$ (well, technically it does, but it replaces it with $x^0$ and $[x_1,x_2]$, which is equivalent to $[x_1,x_2]$, since $x^0$ evaluates to $e$ in any group, so it does not contribute to the verbal subgroup).

Since the value of a commutator word in a group $G$ is necessarily contained in $[G,G]$, if $W$ is a set of group words that includes $[x_1,x_2]$, then we can replace $W$ with a new set, $W'$, which consists of $[x_1,x_2]$ and power words; and then $W(G)=W'(G)$ for every group $G$.

Moreover, in any group, the subgroup generated by all $n$th powers and all $m$th powers is equal to the subgroup generated by all $\gcd(n,m)$th powers: clearly the latter contains the former, since very $n$th power is also a $\gcd(n,m)$th power; and if $\gcd(m,n) = \alpha n + \beta m$ with $\alpha,\beta$ integers, then $x^{\gcd(m,n)} = x^{\alpha n + \beta m} = (x^n)^{\alpha}(x^m)^{\beta}$, so $x^{\gcd(m,n)}$ lies in the subgroup generated by all $n$th and $m$th powers.

Thus, if $W$ is a set of words that consists of $[x_1,x_2]$ and a collection of power words, then we can replace $W$ with a set $W'$ that contains only $[x_1,x_2]$ and a single power word $x^a$ for some $a\geq 0$; and then for any group $G$, we have $W(G)=W'(G)$.

Thus, any set of words $W$ that determines a variety of abelian groups is equivalent to a set $W'$ of the form $W'=\{[x_1,x_2],x^n\}$ for some $n\geq 0$; in the sense that for every group $G$, $W(G)=W'(G)$.

Since a variety of groups corresponds to a set of words $W$, and is determined as "all groups for which $W(G)$ is trivial", we conclude that a variety of abelian groups corresponds to a nonnegative integer $n\geq 0$, and is determined as "all abelian groups $G$ for which $g^n = e$ for all $g\in G$." That is, the abelian groups of exponent $n$. Denote this variety by $\mathcal{Ab}_n$. Note that the variety of all abelian groups is $\mathcal{Ab}_0$.

So the varieties of abelian groups are precisely the varieties $\mathcal{Ab}_n$, for some fixed $n\geq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

The following argument is basically the same as Arturo's above, but somewhat streamlined in presentation.

Suppose I have some word $$p=x_1^{z_1}x_2^{z_2}...x_n^{z_n}$$ with $z_i\in\mathbb{Z}$; I claim that there is some $k$ such that the abelian groups in which $p$ evaluates to $1$ on all inputs are exactly those groups where every element has order dividing $k$.

First, since we're only looking at abelian groups we can assume WLOG that $x_i\not=x_j$ whenever $1\le i<j\le n$. Let $k=gcd\{\vert z_1\vert ,...,\vert z_n\vert\}$. Clearly if $G$ is an abelian group where every element has order dividing $k$ we get $p(g_1,...,g_n)=1_G$ for all $g_1,...,g_n\in G$. In the opposite direction, let $g\in G$; I claim that $g^{\vert z_i\vert}=1_G$ for each $1\le i\le n$.

To see this, fix such an $i$ and consider the variable assignment $\nu$ defined by $$x_u=\begin{cases}
g & \mbox{if $u=i$,}\\
1_G & \mbox{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$ If $p$ always evaluates to $1_G$ in $G$, we must have $p[\nu]=1_G$. But $p[\nu]=g$.

---

Strictly speaking we're not done; the above classifies the varieties **determined by a single word**. But each variety is an intersection of such single-word varieties, and any intersection of "$\mathcal{Ab}_m$-classes" is again an "$\mathcal{Ab}_m$-class," using Arturo's notation here. (Note that this latter fact is just a rephrasing of the Noetherianness of $\mathbb{Z}$!)